# Customize Remote video view and local video view using PJSIP lib in IOS

Tags: ios, call, pjsip, remoteview, videocall

I want to display remote video in fullscreen and local video display small view in right side like whatsapp video call.

```
   var size = pjmedia_rect_size()
   size.h = 924//UInt32(screenSize.height * 0.9)
   size.w = 624//UInt32(screenSize.width * 0.9)
   let statusWinSize =  pjsua_vid_win_set_size(wid, &size)
```

Already set this size but not set proper view so i'm stuck in this view
Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: how to fetch local video and put on local video view. Can you send the code?

Comment: Yes, You can get on_call_media_state this method.

Comment: let wid = media[Int(mi)].stream.vid.win_in;
 var wi = pjsua_vid_win_info();

let vid_win:UIView =          Unmanaged<UIView>.fromOpaque(wi.hwnd.info.ios.window).takeUnretainedValu;
I only get a remote view but how fetch local?

Comment: let i1  =  (wid == PJSUA_INVALID_ID.rawValue) ? 0 : Int(wid);
                let last1  =  (wid == PJSUA_INVALID_ID.rawValue) ? Int(PJSUA_MAX_VID_WINS): Int(wid + 1);
                for j in i1...last1 {
                    var wi =  pjsua_vid_win_info()
                    if (pjsua_vid_win_get_info(pjsua_vid_win_id(j), &wi) == PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue) {

Comment: let vid_win:UIView =  Unmanaged<UIView>.fromOpaque(wi.hwnd.info.ios.window).takeUnretainedValue();
                      
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if ((wi.is_native == 0)) {
                                // Remote view
                            } else  {
                                
                                //DISPLAY SELF PREVIEW
                               
                            }
                        }
                    }